# destructuring specific properties from complex object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm making an api request that returns an object with a drinks property which is an array of drink objects. The drink objects have two properties of interest for me, id, and name. Is there a simple way to destructure the data so I get just an array of objects with the id and name of each drink?

The best way I can think of is to do the following:

```
 const {drinks} = await [api request]
 const arrDrinks = drinks.map((drinkObj, i) => {
      return {drinkObj.idDrink, drinkObj.strDrink}
    })
```

Would there be a way to do this in one line through nested destructuring?

Comment: No, there's not. But what's wrong with an object that has all the properties? You can normally use it in any place that requires only the two you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have used for the returned object literal is not correct. Use destructuring in the parameter:

```
const arrDrinks = drinks.map(({idDrink, strDrink}) => ({idDrink, strDrink}));
```